# strong object being released

Tags: iphone, xcode, delegates, uitabbarcontroller, automatic-ref-counting

I have a strange problem in which I am trying to set a custom UIView object to have a delegate which is a custom tab bar controller.  The tab bar controller is being set as the delegate and I am positive it is not nil then, and it infact is set!  However later on when the custom UIView performs its task, the delegate is nil.

I am using ARC and I made sure that the object is strong even though the tab bar in question is inside a UINavBar so it should not be getting released...

I am starting to think that there is no way that the UITabBar is actually getting released, because it quite clearly still exists...  I'm also quite certain I am setting it as the delegate in the appropriate way.

I set the delegate inside a ViewDidLoad of one of the ViewControllers held by the UITabViewController.
Here is how I set the delegate:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    customSearchBar.delegate = (id<SearchResultReceiver>)self.tabBarController;
    //customSearchBar.delegate IS SET, btw tabBarController implements SearchResultReceiver
    ...
}
```

As I said, the id delegate has properties (strong, nonatomic) even though I don't believe it needs to be strong.  seems like it should be weak since the TabBarController is already owned somewhere else by a NavigationBarController, still I wanted to be safe when I saw this problem.

Here is the code where delegate is nil, now we are in the CustomSearchBar.m
Not sure if it matters, and certainly you've guessed it, but... CustomSearchBar.m is a UITextFieldDelegate.

The following code is called by a Communicator object which handles url requests and turns incoming/outgoing jsons into dictionaries, it is working fine.  Just pretend that the following is called by a -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection...

```
-(void)receiveData:(NSDictionary *)dict forMode:(int)mode
{
    [self.delegate receiveSearchResult:dict];
    [spinner stopAnimating];
    [searchConnection cancel];
}
```

Now the delegate is nil.  No where else in the code do I ask for customSearchBar's delegate.

Additional Information:

CustomSearchBar extends UIView and is an IBOutlet to the ViewController which owns it.  That ViewController is owned by the TabBarController that I'm trying to set as delegate.

Thanks for your time, and let me know if I can provide more details.  Not having a clue as to why a problem occurs results in poor presentation :'( sarry!

Here is some more information about the synthesis of delegate...

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Communicator.h"

@protocol SearchResultReceiver <NSObject>

@optional
-(void) receiveSearchResult:(NSDictionary *) dict;

@end

@interface CustomSearchBar : UIView <UITextFieldDelegate, DataReceiver>
{
    __strong id <SearchResultReceiver> delegate;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) id<SearchResultReceiver> delegate;
...
```

and in the .m i do @synthesize delegate; simply

Comment: Please include the definition of your delegate property and any synthesize statements. Note that when accessing properties, you should use the dot syntax, eg self.delegate, rather than delegate.

Comment: Thanks. I updated the dot notation and found that it is still nil at the receiveData stage.  The rest of the information I will provide shortly.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out!

It was a frustrating problem, but I had accidently made two UIViews into CustomSearchBars, and I was setting the delegate in one of them where as the other one was the active one: it remained unset.

I feel foolish.